# How to pass variable name as collection name for mongo db in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-modules

I am using node js and mongo db and I want to pass a variable to collections

```
var id = "someid";
db.collection(id).insert("some json data");
```

If I did like this it is giving me an error as collection name must be a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create variable using var for collection name

```
var colName = "mytest"
```

and then execute all the operations on collections as below:

```
db[colName].find()
db[colName].rename("newName")
```

etc. This will help you keep your collection name dynamic and can even update it keeping your commands same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @karthik ponnam please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: Is it possible to set collection name dynamically through variables using mongoose?